# Storing daily event start and end times in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I currently have an Events table that stores the event and what days of the week the event occurs, the table looks something like this.

```
EventID  Title       Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
1        EventName   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
```

I want to be able to add START and END times for each event, usually I would just add two extra columns such as StartTime and EndTime, but the start and end times are often different for on each day of the week.

What would be the best way to set up my tables to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Best how? There is not a single best ever. You'll have to define the conditions for it. Best in speed? Best in extensibility? Best in flexilibity? Besti in storage space?

Comment: Seems a bad design to start with - can you have mon tue...sun mon tue...sun and so on on the same row for the same event id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You should add Table Event_Details with below schema

EventDetailsID
EventID (Foreign Key)
Mon_Timings
Tue_Timings
Wed_Timings
Thrus_Timings
Fri_Timings
Sat_Timings
Sun_Timings

Sample data entry for the Event_Details table should be like below


EventDetailsID = 1
EventID  = 1
Mon_Timings = 08:00-20:00  
Tue_Timings = 09:00-19:00
Wed_Timings = NULL
Thrus_Timings = NULL
Fri_Timings = 10:30-21:30
Sat_Timings = NULL
Sun_Timings = NULL

At time of saving data you can have StartTime-EndTime format
and when you want to retrieve you can split by '-'

This will have less number of rows , which will retrieve data faster
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with two solutions:

#### Solution 1: Separate Table

Create another table with Event ID and day of week as primary keys, and each has START and END

```
 EventID  Day  Start  End
```

Pros: no nulls, less space if the events are "sparse"
Cons: needs a join

#### Solution 2: Columns

It looks like this:

```
EventID  Title       Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun MonStart MonEnd TueStart TueEnd ... SunStart SunEnd
```

Pros: less space if the events are "dense", no need for join